# CSS: Background position relative to element

Tags: html, css

I am working on website that have in the header "two lines" must repeat Horizontally
and footer,
I have already made a background repeat imgage for the two lines

**How to make the "second background repeat image" position same as "footer div" position ..**

Actually I make the two line in the top to be one "background repeat image"...

HTML Code:

```html
<body>
<div id="websiteContents">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headerLine"></div>
        contents
        <div id="headerLine_down"></div>
    </div>
    vary contents
    <div class="footer">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">about</a>
        <a href="#">contact us</a>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS Code:

```css
body {
    background: url(../images/standard/repeat_header.png) #FFF repeat-x 0 165px;
}

#websiteContents {
    width: 1150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#headerLine {
width: 1150px;
height: 4px;
background-color: #647193;
float: left;
margin-top: 14px;
 }

 #headerLine_down {
      width: 1150px;
      height: 9px;
      background-color: #2B303E;
 }

.footer {
    width: 1150px;
    background-color: #2A2F3D;
    other styles...
}
```

[The Screenshot](http://i39.tinypic.com/5d4h2r.png)

The web site is too large so if you want the full code I will give you

Thank you all

Comment: can you share a screenshot, so that we can understand your requirement.

Comment: do you have a footer in your header?

Comment: I am sorry I will edit this and post a screenshot

Comment: @Sonasish Roy I am working on the screenshot I will post it

Comment: cant u jsut add a background-image into the footer?

Comment: @SonasishRoy This is the screenshot http://i39.tinypic.com/5d4h2r.png

Comment: The Screenshot is: i39.tinypic.com/5d4h2r.png, and the code is correct

Comment: @ErikMes no if i add background image to the footer it will be just on the footer div I want it to fill(like the screenshot)

Comment: Is it a color? if so, why dont you set a background-color.. It is very unclear what you want

Comment: @ErikMes thats what I am looking for [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24x4aq1&s=5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you

I have changed your html structure

**html**

```
<div id="websiteContents">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="headerContainer">
            <div id="headerLine"></div>
            contents
            <div id="headerLine_down"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bodyContainer">
    vary contents
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footerContainer">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">about</a>
            <a href="#">contact us</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
    background: url(../images/standard/repeat_header.png) #FFF repeat-x 0 165px;
}
body, html{
    height:100%;    
}

#websiteContents {
    height:100%;
}
#headerLine {
    width: 1150px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #647193;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 14px;
}

 #headerLine_down {
      width: 1150px;
      height: 9px;
      background-color: #2B303E;
 }

.footer {
    background-color: #2A2F3D;
    height:100%;
}

.headerContainer{
    width:1150px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.bodyContainer{
    width:1150px;
    margin:0 auto;  
}
.footerContainer{
    width:1150px;
    margin:0 auto;  
}
```

Comment: oh sorry i will post the picture for the jsFiddle File and the wrong thing

Comment: just min. I am making the screenshot

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24x4aq1&s=5

Comment: I do not understand what is the change

Comment: there is no width in #websiteContents, #header is full width, .footer is also full width

Answer (score 0):

I'm stil not sure, if I understood... but do you think something like this ?

[**jsFIddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/HcB3H/)

CSS

```
.footer {
    width: 1150px;
    background-color: #2A2F3D;
    background-image:url('http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/smiley.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: no i want the background to be in the body tag to fill the body with that color if your screen was wide the background will repeat to fill it

Comment: can you look at the screenshot